# notify the user for @username in a comment?

Tags: notifications, activity-streams

When a user includes @another-user in a comment, I'd like to notify the `another-user` about it.

I've been using activity stream (django implementation is [here,](https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/master/docs/source/index.rst) but this question has nothing to do with django), and I could make each user to follow himself to make the system work for this scenario.

`user-a mentions user-b in post-1`

If each user follows himself, he would get notification about the above activity.

Still, I'm not comfortable with the idea of one following oneself, feel like abusing the system.

Is there a better design for this `mention` notification?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about django activity streams, have a look at some of the alternatives:
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/activities/

For getstream.io for instance you would simply use the TO support:
https://getstream.io/docs/#targetting

Also using Stream-Framework you could achieve this by sending an extra list of feeds to fanout to.

Cheers,
Thierry